Textbook to complement Evans' PDEs in Machine Learning?
I am particularly interested in physics-informed machine learning (PINNs, PINOs, DeepONets, etc.). Specifically, the theory of neural operators seems to rely heavily on functional analysis and the existence of Green's functions or fundamental solutions.
Having gained a strong theoretical background from Lawrence C. Evans' Partial Differential Equations, and now moving into machine learning, I am seeking suggestions for good complementary books on this physics-informed approach.
